# How to analyse pre-post ordinal data?

Tags: categorical-data, ordinal-data, pre-post-comparison

I collected pre-post data from a randomized controlled experiment. The intervention for the experiment group is an educational game and the pre-test and post-test contains 10  multiple-choice questions. The data is coded as 1= correct and 0=incorrect.
What is the right statistical test to analyse pre-post test?

Comment: Does this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs  answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best practice when analysing pre-post treatment-control designs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs)

Comment: Thanks, from my basic understanding, that the type of data which not continues will require a different type of statistical test than the once in that question.